# Keep updating values. (ajax - poll from .php file)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to modify this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

I'm just using the HTML part of that ^. My php file only have

```
<?php
echo rand();
?>
```

And it works fine! It updates every time I switch something on the drop-down list.
But, I want it to run every second, but it won't work. This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/test.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
setInterval(showUser, 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="txtHint"><b>this will be updated</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The SetInterval won't run it. The php file is still only echo rand();.
It worked at some point but I screwed something up I believe. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInterval()` is likely running just fine, but `showUser()` is ending with an error since `str` is not defined.  Check your JavaScript console for errors.

Either remove the reference to `str`, or define it somewhere.

Comment: This is the fourth time today that I have seen this code copied and pasted from W3Schools. I wonder if all of these people are in the same class?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Lol no, just wanted to try some stuff out.

Comment: @PaulRoub - Great.. Didn't think of that, was going to use it later but removed the thing that defined it for the moment, works now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 setInterval(function(){showUser()}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
setInterval(showUser, 1000);
```

with

```
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(showUser, 1000);
}
```